# Any solution for using vim plugin YouCompleteMe with RVM?

Tags: ruby, vim, rvm

I'm trying use YouCompleteMe for Rails dev on VIM. VIM always crash if I use YCM with RVM ruby. I'm reinstall YCM with system ruby, everything work find but when I use RVM ruby, VIM crash again.

Comment: If vim crashes with YCM file a bug report.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/detail?id=114&thanks=114&ts=1361483471
Old but possibly relevant